Differential Operator in Curvilinear Coordinates
I am trying to understand how to derive the formula
$\nabla f=\sum_i\frac{1}{h_i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}\hat{r}_i$ for the gradient in general coordinates.
Prelude. Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the usual cartesian coordinates and $\hat{x}_i$ their associated basis vectors. If $y_1,y_2,y_3$ denote curvilinear coordinates such that $x_i=x_i(y_j)$, then $\boldsymbol{r}=\sum_ix_i\hat{x}_i=x_i(y)\hat{x}_i$. The basis vectors associated to the curvilinear coordinates are (eq. 1):
$$\boldsymbol{r}_j=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial y_j}=\sum_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_j}\hat{x}_i.$$
The basis vectors $\boldsymbol{r}_j$ are not of unit length; denote their norm by $||\boldsymbol{r}_j||=h_j$. Moreover, since the transformations $x_i=x_i(y_j)$ are invertible, then by differentiating $\boldsymbol{r}(x)=\boldsymbol{r}(y(x))$ we obtain the inverse relations (eq. 2):
$$\hat{x}_j=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial x_j}=\sum_i\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial y_i}\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}=\sum_i\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\boldsymbol{r}_i.$$
Question. The entries of matrix of the change of basis from $\{\hat{x}_i\}$ to the curvilinear basis $\{\boldsymbol{r}_j\}$ are $J_{ij}=\partial x_i/\partial y_j$, while the entries of the inverse transformation are $J_{ij}^{-1}=\partial y_i/\partial x_j$. Since $\nabla f$ is a vector, then it should be possible to find its components in the new basis $\{\boldsymbol{r}_j\}$ simply by applying equation (2), namely:
$$\nabla f=\sum_j\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\hat{x}_j=\sum_j\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\sum_i\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\boldsymbol{r}_j,$$
which clearly doesn't give the desired result. But honestly I don't really understand why... What did I do wrong? I am asking because on the other hand, projecting the gradient $\nabla f$ onto the basis $\{\hat{r}_j\}$, where $\hat{r}_i=\boldsymbol{r}_i/h_i$, and using equation (1) gives the following result:
$$\nabla f=\sum_k\langle\nabla f,\hat{r}_k\rangle\hat{r}_k=\sum_k\Bigl\langle\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\hat{x}_i,\frac{1}{h_k}\sum_j\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_k}\hat{x}_j\Bigr\rangle\hat{r}_k=...=\sum_k\frac{1}{h_k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_k}\hat{r}_k,$$
that is correct. I shall deduce that equation (2) is then incorrect? Where is the mistake in the first way of doing it?

There is a typo in the third equation: $\bf{r}_j$ should be $\bf{r}_i$.

I'm not convinced that your expressions for the inverse transformation (i.e., $\hat{x}_j$ in terms of $\mathbf{r}_i$) is correct, since both the components $y_i$ and the basis vectors $\mathbf{r}_i$ depend on the coordinates $x_j$. Perhaps the notation plus the partial derivatives are mixing me up here, but are you sure about Equation (2)? I agree that the last equation is correct (and likely the correct way to think about it), but I also agree that we should be able to get there by careful use of partial derivatives and chain rules.

There is no contradiction here. Just use the definition of $h_k = \sum_j \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_k}$ and you will get the correct result. You can easily derive this relation from your definition of $\bf{r}_k$.

The gradient (or the contravariant version of the covariant derivative ) of a scalar is defined as $$\nabla \phi=\sum_k \boldsymbol {e}k\partial_k \phi$$, where ${\boldsymbol e_k}{k}$ is a a coordinate basis. To convert to a normalized basis, in which the vectors $\boldsymbol e_k$ all have magnitude $1$, one simply needs to write $$\nabla \phi=\sum_k \hat{\boldsymbol {e}}_k~\frac{1}{h_k}\partial_k \phi $$, where $h_k:=\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol e_k|}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol e}_k:=h_k \boldsymbol e_k$.

@K.defaoite So basically by definition $$\nabla\phi=\sum_k\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y_k}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial y_k},$$ where $\boldsymbol{r}_k=\partial_k\boldsymbol{r}$ is what you call the coordinate basis. Does this come from the fact that $\phi$ is the scalar field $\boldsymbol{r}(y_1,y_2,y_3)\mapsto\phi(\boldsymbol{r}(y_1,y_2,y_3))$ and therefore by differentiating: $$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y_k}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial y_k}.$$ But then how to relate this with the definition you gave?

@Sidd I'm sorry but I don't see how. Do you mean to use the fact that $h_k=\sum_j\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_k}$ in equation: $$\nabla f=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}\boldsymbol{r}_i?$$

@march Honestly I am not 100% sure about equation 2, but honestly I don't see why it should be incorrect, because I am just differentiating an equation: $\boldsymbol{r}(x)=\boldsymbol{r}(y(x))$ which should be true independently on the fact that the basis vectors $\boldsymbol{r}_j$ depend upon the coordinates $y_i$. In the end, if $x_i=x_i(y_j)$ are invertible, then it's always possible to convert into $y_j=y_j(x_i)$. Also $\boldsymbol{r}$ is an invariant object, so $\boldsymbol{r}(x)=\boldsymbol{r}(y(x))$ must be valid. What do you think?

@Falcy87 I would fix the typo first.

@Falcy87 $\mathbf{r}(x) = \mathbf{r}(y(x))$ is the way we would write is as physicists, but mathematically speaking, that doesn't make sense, because we are using $\mathbf{r}$ as the name of the object not the name of the functional form. That is, I would write that more carefully as $\mathbf{r}(x) = \tilde{\mathbf{r}}(y(x))$, where $\mathbf{r}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{r}}$ are two different functions (that represent the same object). Nonetheless, your point is well taken, and that's why I said I was "non entirely convinced", because I'm just not sure.

@K.defaoite That seems to be side-stepping the issue, then, because if the gradient is defined in that way, then it becomes necessary to show that the gradient is basis- and coordinate-independent, which is essentially what the OP is trying to do.

@march Thanks for your answer and yes you're absolutely right. Then, the Jacobians $\boldsymbol{J}=(\partial x_i/\partial y_j)$ and $\boldsymbol{J}^{-1}=(\partial y_i/\partial x_j)$ are the inverses of each other and they also represent the change of basis between ${\hat{x}_i}$ and ${\boldsymbol{r}_j}$, according to eq. (1) $\boldsymbol{r}_a=\boldsymbol{J}\hat{x}_a$. Since $\boldsymbol{J}$ is invertible it follows that $\hat{x}_a=\boldsymbol{J}^{-1}\boldsymbol{r}_a$. But at this point I think that we cannot threat $\nabla$ as any other vector, thus the ordinary change of basis doesn't work

The main point is to show that the object
$$\omega_i=\nabla_i\phi=\partial_i\phi$$
Is a (co)-vector, i.e with a coordinate transform $x\leftrightarrow\bar{x}$ its components transform as
$$\bar{\partial}_i\phi=\bar{\omega}_{i}=\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial\bar{x}^{i}}\omega_j$$
However, this final line is simply an expression of the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial\bar{x}^i}=\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial\bar{x}^i}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial\bar{x}^i}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^2}+\cdots$$
And is obviously true. Thus, $\boldsymbol \omega$ as written is a proper covector.

Again, this all uses the coordinate bases
$$\boldsymbol e_k(\boldsymbol x):=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol x}{\partial x^k}$$
$$\bar{\boldsymbol e}_k(\boldsymbol x):=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial\bar{x}^k}$$
However we can simply re-express the results in terms of the normalized bases if we so wish, as I expressed in the comments.
Also, this is technically not the gradient but the covariant derivative, but the gradient is simply the sharped (or index-raised) version of the covariant derivative (i.e $\operatorname{grad}\phi:=(\nabla\phi)^{\sharp}$  ,  $(\operatorname{grad}\phi)^i=g^{ij}(\nabla\phi)_j$), and via fundamental differential geometry theory transforms as a vector.

Thanks a lot for your answer! I was trying what follows: If $\boldsymbol{r}=x_i(y)\hat{x}_i$, then define $$\boldsymbol{r}_j=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_j}\hat{x}_i.$$ Consider the field $f(x)=f(x(y))=f^(y)=f^(y(x))$. By differentiating: $$\partial_if=\frac{\partial f^}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}.$$ Then $$\nabla f=\partial_if\hat{x}_i=\frac{\partial f^}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}\hat{x}_i,$$ but I can't replace $$\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}\hat{x}_i$$ with $\boldsymbol{r}_j$, because it's not the same expression found above...

@Falcy87 I'm having a hard time following what you're doing.

I am just trying to find a way to get analytically from $$\nabla=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\hat{x}_i$$ in Cartesian coordinates, to $$\nabla=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\boldsymbol{r}_i=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\frac{1}{h_i}\hat{r}_i$$ in curvilinear coordinates.

I'm sorry it is late where I am, I believe that $\partial y_j/\partial x_i=\frac{1}{\partial x_i/\partial y_j}$ should get you what you are looking for
